# How do I make macOS remember projector color settings?

Tags: display, color, projector

I'm fighting with macOS over Epson EH-TW450 projector color settings.

When I go to Settings → Displays → Display Settings → Colour Profile → Projector..., I get a nice panel for adjusting the projector gamma and white balance:

[image: projector color settings]

The problem is, after I move the slider up, which makes everything brighter (good!), the projector brightness smoothly goes down to the original level over the next few seconds. The slider stays up, but the brightness isn't the same. When I click the slider again (without moving it), the display becomes brighter again, but again only for a while. How do I make my Mac remember this setting?

I also tried various color profiles from the list, but none of them gives me the brightness I want and I also didn't find a way to control the gamma manually. And my projector has no brightness/gamma setting either :(

I'm using macOS Monterey 12.4.

Comment: Make and model of the projector would be helpful. And the projector *might* be set up to adjust itself automatically. In other words there might be something strange going on in the Mac, or some preset in the projector that causes this behavior.

Comment: The projector is an Epson EH-TW450, but I'm quite sure it's not the problem - it's clearly the slider in macOS: clicking it remediates the problem, just for a very short time.

Comment: Look up 'auto iris'. It sounds like you're fighting its built-in auto adjustment.

Comment: No. First, this projector does not have auto iris. Second, this doesn't match what happens - I click a slider in macOS, without changing its value, and then it "recalls" the value I set, but then forgets it again after a while. This setting is clearly in macOS, not the projector. And the fact if doesn't stick looks like a macOS bug - I'm looking for a workaround.